# Properties of a transitive group acting on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is a transitive group acting on $S$ with $n$ elements, show that $n$ divides $|G|$.

my thoughts

$gStab_G(s)$=$hStab_G(s)$ for some g and h

```
        =>$h^{-1}g$ Element of $Stab_(s)$  
        =>$h^{-1}gs$  =$s$
        =>$gs=hs$
```

$|G|$=$|Stab_G(s)$*$|Orb(s)|$

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what you tried to do in your question (though your last equality is true), but $\;G\;$ is transitive on that set with $\;n\;$ elements iff there is one single orbit, thus for any $\;x\;$ in that set we get

$$n=|\mathcal O(x)|=[G:Stab(x)|=\frac{|G|}{|Stab(x)|}$$

and we're done.